# Backbone. My View has rewriten for each object

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

This is my HTML

```
<div class="productsContainer">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="products">
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="productsTemplate">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#<%= title %>" aria-controls="<%= title %>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
            <%= title %>
    </a></li>
</script>
```

This is my JS:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Product,
url: '/*server url*/'
});

var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize:function(options){
    console.log(this.el);
    return this.render();
},
el:'div.productsContainer ul',

template:  _.template( $('#productsTemplate').html() ),

render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},

renderEL: function(item){
    var productView = new ProductView({
        model: item
    });
}
});


var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({

el:'div.productsContainer ul',

initialize:function(options){
    this.collection = new Products(options.collection);
    this.collection.fetch({reset:true, add:true});
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderProduct);
    return this;
},
render:function(){
    this.collection.each(function(item){
        this.renderProduct(item);     
    }, this);

    return this;
},

renderProduct: function(item){
    var productView = new ProductView({
        model: item
    });

    this.$el.append(productView.render().$el);
}
});

var productsView = new ProductsView({});
$("div.productsContainer").append(productsView.render().$el);
```

When i used in "var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({})" tagName:'li', script has added each object, but i get 'li''li''/li''/li'....,so i has use el:''ul'....but script rewrites each object in one element 'li'. how i can realization my script, for each object to add a new tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 'li''li''/li''/li' because ProductView creates 'li' tag automatically (tagName: 'li') and your template contains also 'li' which is appended/inserted into 'li'. Just remove 'li' from the template and keep 'a' only.

If the 'li' should have any class/attribute use 'className' (className:'active') or 'attributes' (attributes: {role: 'presentation'}) while constructing the view (http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor).

Comment: Thank you , I spent over 5 hours, and it's so easy

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer if your issue is solved.